# Calling object functions

Tags: javascript

I am confused how to define and call JavaScript object methods. I'm attempt to create a game in JavaScript and want to create objects with functions to control each element. Currently, the `game.update` function calls an error when it tries to call `player.update`. It can't find the method. How should I go about defining and calling methods. I come from using java.

```
//INIT
var game;
var paper;
var key = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // left, right, up, down

window.onload = function () {
    paper = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);
    game = new Game();
    game.init();
};

//GAME
function Game() {
    this.player = new Player();
    this.score = 0;

    this.drawCanvas = function () {
        paper.clear();
        paper.rect(0, 0, 640, 480, 10).attr({
            fill: "#fff",
            stroke: "none"
        });
        paper.text(40, 10, "Score " + this.score);
        paper.ellipse(this.player.positionX, this.player.positionY, 10, 10);
    }

    this.update = function () {
        this.player.update.call();
        this.drawCanvas.call()();
    }

    this.init = function () {
        this.drawCanvas();
        setInterval(this.update, 35);
    }
}

//UNITS

//PLAYER
function Player() {
    this.positionX = 100;
    this.positionY = 100;

    this.update = function () {
        if (key[0]) { //left
            this.positionX -= 3;
            game.score += 3;
        }
        if (key[1]) { //right
            this.positionX += 3;
            game.score += 3;
        }
        if (key[2]) { //up
            this.positionY -= 3;
            game.score += 3;
        }
        if (key[3]) { //down
            this.positionY += 3;
            game.score += 3;
        }
        if (key[4]) { //space

        }

        if (this.positionX > 640) {
            this.positionX = 640;
        } else if (this.positionX < 0) {
            this.positionX = 0;
        } else if (this.positionY > 480) {
            this.positionY = 480;
        } else if (this.positionY < 0) {
            this.positionY = 0;
        }
    }
}

function changeKey(which, to) {
    switch (which) {
        case 65:
        case 37:
            key[0] = to;
            break; // left
        case 87:
        case 38:
            key[2] = to;
            break; // up
        case 68:
        case 39:
            key[1] = to;
            break; // right
        case 83:
        case 40:
            key[3] = to;
            break; // down
        case 32:
            key[4] = to;
            break; // space bar;
        case 17:
            key[5] = to;
            break; // ctrl
    }
}
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    changeKey((e || window.event).keyCode, 1);
};
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    changeKey((e || window.event).keyCode, 0);
};
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined      main.js:25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here where you've detached the `update` method from `this`.

```
this.init = function () {
    this.drawCanvas();
    setInterval(this.update, 35); // <-------- passing `update` without `this`
}
```

So when you get to this line in `update()`

```
this.player.update.call();
```

The value of `this` is the global object, which has no `player` property, so you're trying to access `.update.call()` on `undefined`.

---

You need to keep them bound:

```
this.init = function () {
    this.drawCanvas();
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function() {
       self.update();
    }, 35);
}
```

---

Or use `Function.prototype.bind` to create a new function with `this` bound permanently to the function.

```
this.init = function () {
    this.drawCanvas();
    setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 35);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. However now I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'positionX' of undefined" on line 21. But I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Probably because you're not passing a `this` value to `.call()`. The first argument you give it needs to be whatever you want to set as its `this` value. If you don't need a special `this` value, then just do `this.player.update();`

Comment: ...and this is certainly wrong too ;-) `this.drawCanvas.call()();`

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid syntax:

```
this.update : function(){
```

you want just this

```
this.update = function(){
```

Comment: But that would be a SyntaxError, not a TypeError.

Comment: I actually forgot to change that back. It was actually and = sign. I was just playing around